# How to verbose log dhcp messages with options values

Tags: logging, dhcp, pxe-boot, debugging

I am trying to configure dhcp PXE server, but client is not booting as expected. Is there a way how you can watch transferred requested and responded options between client and server?
I want to be able to see each individual option value.

Answer (score 1):

Use dhcpdump -i eth0. This show nicely the content for the dhcp packets.

Answer (score 0):

I did not found a way how to do it via system logs when using ISC DHCP. But I have found a super convenient and easy way to solve the task of debugging.

**Just use Wireshark**. Start it as Superuser, then start capturing packets of a needed network interface. Initiate DHCP request from a client. Then in Protocol column you will see packets marked as DHCP. Click at one you are interested in. Then you are able to see contents of that package.

Answer (score 0):

If using isc dhcpd, you can use log function for debugging: https://docs.menandmice.com/display/MM/using+the+log+function+for+debugging